# Testing JS exceptions with Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js, chai

Trying to test some code that throws an exception with Mocha/Chai, but having no luck, here's the simple code I'm trying to test:

```
class window.VisualizationsManager

  test: ->
    throw(new Error 'Oh no')
```

Here is my test:

```
describe 'VisualizationsManager', ->

  it 'does not permit the construction of new instances', ->

    manager = new window.VisualizationsManager

    chai.expect(manager.test()).to.throw('Oh no')
```

However, when I run the spec, the test fails and throws the exception.

```
Failure/Error: Oh no
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's probably because you are executing the function right away, so the test framework cannot handle the error.

Try something like:

```
chai.expect(manager.test.bind(manager)).to.throw('Oh no')
```

If you know that you aren't using the `this` keyword inside the function I guess you could also just pass `manager.test` without binding it.

Also, your test name doesn't reflect what the code does. If it doesn't permet the construction of new instances, `manager = new window.VisualizationsManager` should fail.

Answer (score 46):

Either **pass the function**:

```
chai.expect(manager.test).to.throw('Oh no');
```

Or **use an anonymous function**:

```
chai.expect(() => manager.test()).to.throw('Oh no');
```

See the [documentation on the `throw` method](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) to learn more.

Comment: this should be the best answer IMO