# When using Mocha and chai, when to wrap expectation with a function?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js, chai

For code that throws exceptions, I need to wrap the expectation in an anonymous function. Otherwise the exception is thrown before it can be caught by Mocha.
See this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933027/2003429).

But wrapping seems to have side effects.
The following code behaves differently when wrapped. it seems to be a Chai problem.

```coffeescript
chai = require 'chai'
expect = chai.expect

describe 'Weird', ->

  obj =
    name: 'kalle'

  it 'not wrapped', () ->
    expect(obj).to.have.property 'name', 'kalle'

  it 'wrapped', () ->
    expect(->obj).to.have.property 'name', 'kalle'
```

My handcrafted Javascript version:

```js
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Weird', function() {
    obj = {name: 'kalle'};

    it('not wrapped', function() {
      expect(obj).to.have.property('name', 'kalle');
    });

    it('wrapped', function() {
        expect(function() {return obj}).to.have.property('name', 'kalle');
    });
});
```

The failure looks like this:
`AssertionError: expected [Function] to have a property 'name' of 'kalle', but got ''`

```
Weird
    ✓ not wrapped 
    1) wrapped


  1 passing (10ms)
  1 failing

  1) Weird wrapped:

      + expected - actual

      +kalle
```

Why does the wrapping yield different results?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it failing in both the javascript and coffeescript versions, or just the CS verison?

Comment: @JedSchneider: Both fail.

Comment: I expected so. I'll provide an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you are passing the function as a parameter, not the result of the function. I expect that mocha actually calls the function when you call `to.throw` as is done in the linked SO answer. In order to resolve the function in this situation, you'd want to actually call the function in your expectation:

```
expect(->obj()).to.have.property 'name', 'kalle'
```

Comment: I guess the answeris: when expecting an exception, wrap the function call; otherwise don't. Thanks @Jed for your efforts.