# How to force a function to throw exception when it invoked with Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I want to test the `function B` to catch exception thrown from `function A` with `Mocha/Chai`.

```
function A() {
  // 1. the third party API is called here
  // some exception may be thrown from it
  ...
  // 2. some exception could be thrown here
  // caused by the logic in this function
}

function B() {
  // To catch exception thrown by A()
  try {
     A();
  } catch(err) {
     console.error(err);
  }
  ...
}
```

I want force `A` to throw exception, while doing the test of `B`. So I can make sure the function `B` catch the exception from `A` correctly.

---

After searching some posts:

[Test for expected failure in Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879181/force-mocha-test-to-fail)

[Testing JS exceptions with Mocha/Chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925884/testing-js-exceptions-with-mocha-chai)

I did not find the correct answer.

---

Is my question reasonable? if it is, how to do that test with `Mocha/Chai`?

Comment: Can't you just `throw 'error';` from inside your A function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called mocking. For the sake of test of function `B` you should mock function `A` to behave the proper way. So before the test you define `A` something like `A = function(){ throw new Error('for test');}` call and verify that when called `B` behaves accordingly.

```
describe('alphabet', function(){
    describe('A', function(){
         var _A;
         beforeEach(function(){
             var _A = A; //save original function
             A = function () {
                  throw new Error('for test');
             }
         });
         it('should catch exceptions in third party', function(){
             B();
             expect(whatever).to.be.true;
         });
         afterEach(function(){
             A = _A;//restore original function for other tests
         });
    }
})
```

As you're already using Mocha with Chai you might be interested to look into Sinon. It greatly extends Mocha capabilities. In this case you would use [stubs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) which simplifies mocking and restoring